# Filtering products categorized by user

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

For example, I come to the server data from the user to filter products:

```
    "categorie":"MOBILES & ACCESSORIES, CAMERAS, WOMEN`S APPAREL",
    "summa_min":"10",
    "sum_max":"34"
    ....
```

How to make filtering so that from the database the data were issued only products that meet the incoming data?

That is, all products from the categories "MOBILES & ACCESSORIES, CAMERAS, WOMEN`S APPAREL" and the price from 10 to 34.

Comment: what is the data type of column

Comment: string and integer

Comment: that means product has 3 columns  categorie,summa_min,sum_max right?

Comment: No, it has a price, for example, price = 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below by using where filter

```
 select p.* from products p 
where categories like'%MOBILES & ACCESSORIES, CAMERAS, WOMENS%' 
and price>=10 and price<=34
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need

Comment: What about the single quote in the word "WOMEN`S"...?